# Nested CASE ELSE END Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone tell me why I'm getting an Incorrect Syntax error at the last ELSE statement.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN PolType = 'PKG' THEN 

    CASE WHEN PkgDef & 1 = 1 THEN 'BA ' ELSE

    CASE WHEN PkgDef & 2 = 2 THEN 'BAT' ELSE

    CASE WHEN PkgDef & 4 = 4 THEN 'GS ' ELSE

    CASE WHEN PkgDef & 8 = 8 THEN 'DLR' ELSE

    'ERR' END 
ELSE 
    poltype 
END AS 'PolType'

FROM Parallel_Test.dbo.PolicyG 
WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM Parallel_Test.dbo.policyg) - 10
```

Comment: Is this for MSSQL, MySQL, or what?  Please tell us what SQL you are using.

Comment: (Sql Server 2008) This statement has 4 layers of Nested Case statements was that your intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server then you might be trying to do this:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN PolType = 'PKG' THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN PkgDef & 1 = 1 THEN 'BA ' 
            WHEN PkgDef & 2 = 2 THEN 'BAT' 
            WHEN PkgDef & 4 = 4 THEN 'GS ' 
            WHEN PkgDef & 8 = 8 THEN 'DLR' 
        ELSE 'ERR' 
        END 
    ELSE poltype 
END AS 'PolType'

FROM Parallel_Test.dbo.PolicyG 
WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM Parallel_Test.dbo.policyg) - 10
```

Let me know if I have interpreted your intended logic wrongly.

Comment: Perfect, thanks to all who replied. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not testet, but try:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PolType <> 'PKG' THEN poltype
WHEN PkgDef & 1 = 1 THEN 'BA '
WHEN PkgDef & 2 = 2 THEN 'BAT'
WHEN PkgDef & 4 = 4 THEN 'GS '
WHEN PkgDef & 8 = 8 THEN 'DLR'
ELSE 'ERR'
END AS 'PolType'
FROM Parallel_Test.dbo.PolicyG 
WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM Parallel_Test.dbo.policyg) - 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your case statement is actually doing at the moment (4 layers of nested if)
I added in the other 'end's' that you would need to correct the statement as it was presented. (I do think one of the other solutions is what you are looking for however)

```
    CASE 
        WHEN PkgDef & 1 = 1 THEN 'BA ' 
        ELSE CASE 
                WHEN PkgDef & 2 = 2 THEN 'BAT' 
                ELSE CASE 
                        WHEN PkgDef & 4 = 4 THEN 'GS ' 
                        ELSE CASE 
                            WHEN PkgDef & 8 = 8 THEN 'DLR' 
                            ELSE 'ERR' 
                            END 
                    end
            end

END AS 'PolType'

FROM Parallel_Test.dbo.PolicyG 
WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM Parallel_Test.dbo.policyg) - 10
```